# How to change variant of text input in react admin

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-admin

I wanted to change the variant of TextInput using material UI. The default variant is Standard and **I want to change that to outlined** but not able to do so. Followed documentation for material-ui [Material-ui documentation](https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/)

Below is my code snippet

```
     <TabbedForm>
            <FormTab label="INFO">
                {/* <TextInput disabled label="" source="id" type="hidden"/> */}
                <TextInput label="Name" source="name"  variant="outlined"/>
                <TextInput source="shortdesc" />

            </FormTab>
     </TabbedForm>
```

Comment: It should be `<TextField/>` there is no component such `TextInput ` in Material UI

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass in `variant="standard"` to the react-admin `<TextInput>` component. The issue is that the `<Filter>` and `<Create>` pages, etc, automatically pass in a bunch of props, like record and basePath, which includes `variant: undefined` for some reason. So if you just write `<TextInput variant="standard" ... />`, your prop will get overwritten. And then when the [TextInput component](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/packages/ra-ui-materialui/src/input/TextInput.tsx) passes its props to the [ResettableTextField component](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/packages/ra-ui-materialui/src/input/ResettableTextField.js), the now undefined variant prop gets defaulted to "filled"...

So, you just need to extract the TextInput component out, so that your variant prop comes last in the props order:

```
export const TextInput = props => <RaTextInput {...props} variant="standard" />
```

Personally, I've abstracted this all out into a HOC, because this is what you have to do for all the Inputs that use TextFields:

```
import React from 'react'
import {
  TextInput as RaTextInput,
  NumberInput as RaNumberInput,
  SelectInput as RaSelectInput,
  DateInput as RaDateInput,
  DateTimeInput as RaDateTimeInput,
  NullableBooleanInput as RaNullableBooleanInput,
  AutocompleteInput as RaAutocompleteInput,
} from 'react-admin'

const standardize = Component => props => <Component {...props} variant="standard" />

export const TextInput = standardize(RaTextInput)
export const NumberInput = standardize(RaNumberInput)
export const SelectInput = standardize(RaSelectInput)
export const DateInput = standardize(RaDateInput)
export const DateTimeInput = standardize(RaDateTimeInput)
export const NullableBooleanInput = standardize(RaNullableBooleanInput)
export const AutocompleteInput = standardize(RaAutocompleteInput)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check my code

```
 <TabbedForm>
            <FormTab label="INFO">
                {/* <TextInput disabled label="" source="id" type="hidden"/> */}
                <TextField label="Name" source="name"  variant="outlined"/>
                <TextField source="shortdesc" />

            </FormTab>
     </TabbedForm>
```

check my [fork](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-xrdo1)

Answer (score 0):

React-admin has fixed this.

You can now use the `variant="outlined | standard | filled"` prop on the component enclosing the input.

Ex: SimpleForm, Create, Filter, etc.

[The Git resolution](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/commit/4c1a6f2c6f28e1ea93b5272e41f3298734a4891e)